# Posting the image by Postman using the spring Boot JPA and db H2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Can any one support me, i am doing the simple stuff that is i am try to save image into database that is uploaded by postman i am using STS with spring boot and jpa database is H2. i tried get/put/post/delete from postman on plain text its working fine and also working fine when GET the image in postman. i have issues in posting image

model class code

```
   @Entity
    public class Alian 
    {
        @Id
    private int aid;
    private String aname;
    @Lob
    private byte[] pic;
```

controller class code is. repo is dao class object.

```
 @ResponseBody 
         @RequestMapping(path="/alian",  method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE )

         public Alian Saving(@RequestBody Alian alian, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
         {
            repo.save(alian);   
            return alian;
    }
```

error at postman is.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-13T19:18:47.246+0000",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------175574471409780768513459;charset=UTF-8' not supported",
    "path": "/alian"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't send @RequestBody along with MultipartFile and you don't even need it in your case. Send only MultiPartFile.

```
public Alian Saving(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    Alian alian = new Alian();
    alian.setPic(file.getBytes());
    alian.setAname(file.getOriginalFilename());
    return repo.save(alian);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `multipart/form-data`.

See https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/sending_api_requests/requests#form-data

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you are not adding content-type manually.

There is no need to add a content-type header manually. You are overriding the value set by Postman. Just select form-data in POST request and send your request to see if it works.

Comment: i am not adding content type manually its done automatically and i am just upload the image and send